# if condition failing in VS 2010 Post Build Events

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was trying to make some post build events depends on configuration. However, the if condition failing, either with code 255 or 9009. Even I removed all the code, just using simple one now.

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" ( CALL "notepad" )
else ( CALL "mspaint" )
```

Result 9009

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (  )
else (  )
```

Result 255

Also tried

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" ( echo "test" )
else ( echo "test2" )
```

Result again 9009

I do not understand why its failing with 9009 when I use any command ? and even with 255 when there is nothing.
I have checked the code, it does substitute $(ConfigurationName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is failing with error code 9009 is because you have not structured the if-else 
statement correctly. You cannot put else on the beggining of the line (the rules are the same
as for batch files), use the following method:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (
    CALL "notepad"
) else (
    CALL "mspaint"
)
```

As for the other example, it fails with error code 255 because you did not put any statement
in the brackets (it is illegal).